Kotlin varargs to array
There is a function I want to call in a third-party library:
fun foo(strings: Array<String>)

The array strings is only used for reading, i.e. foo doesn't write to it.
Now, I want to write a function of my own, like this:
fun bar(vararg vstrings: String) {
    do some things...
    foo(vstrings)
    do some more things...
}

But the foo(vstrings) call results in a compilation error: argument type mismatch: actual type is 'Array<CapturedType(out String)>', but 'Array<String>' was expected.
I can't change the signature of foo. How can I pass this vararg parameter as an array?

This is because the vararg parameter is of type Array<out String>, not Array<String>. See also the specification. I think this is to prevent you from modifying the array's elements, which is almost always incorrect.
You can create a copy of the array then pass the copy to foo.
fun bar(vararg vstrings: String) {
    foo(Array(vstrings.size) { vstrings[it] })
}

In Kotlin/JS, you can call vstrings.copyOf() directly, but this is no available on other platforms for some reason.

I suppose also that, as long as I'm guaranteed that foo doesn't modify the array's elements, I can do @Suppress(...) foo(vstrings as Array<String>)?

@k314159 Yes. I think (at least on JVM) even if foo modifies the array elements, you can do that too. It's just that the changes cannot be observed outside of foo, even if you use the * syntax to pass an array you created to bar.
